# Pick the data if a certain number of data for a certain date is present in pandas.DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a beginner in Python. I'm working on a dateset which contains data for several years. This is the sample of the dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQibL.png)

Here, Hour(LT) means time and DN(LT) means Day number of the year.

I have tried in Python 3.0 pandas Anaconda to work on this dataset. My final goal is to find out the daily, weekly, monthly and yearly mean so I preferred to convert it into pandas.DatetimeIndex (by resampling would be quite easy I guess!)

I provided the codes I've written until now.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test_file.txt', sep=' ', delimiter=' ')

#convert the year, month, day int columns into datetime format 
year_month = pd.to_datetime(10000 * df.Year +100 * df.Month +df.Day, format='%Y%m%d')

#convert Year, Month, Day, Hour(LT) into DayTimeHour format
year_hour_convert = pd.DataFrame({
                                        'Day': np.array(year_month, dtype=np.datetime64), 
                                        'Hour': np.array(df['Hour(LT)'], dtype=np.int64)
                                })

#merge into "year-month-day-hour" format
year_hour = pd.to_datetime(year_hour_convert.Day) + pd.to_timedelta(year_hour_convert.Hour, unit='h')

#Define a new column for Time Series
df['DateTime'] = year_hour

#Drop unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour(LT)', 'DN(LT)'], axis=1)

#Set YYYYMMDD HHMMSS as index
df = df.set_index('DateTime')

#Choose the data for 9 a.m. to 3 p.m.
df = df.between_time('09:00:00', '15:00:00')
```

I have turned my dataset into this format. I dropped the `'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour(LT)', 'DN(LT)'`columns eventually. I provided the picture of that format.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elj1m.png)

Now I want to filter the data if a certain number of data is available for a certain day. For instance, if the number of data for 4th Jan, 2016 as well as 2016-01-04 is above 4, I will take the data of that day. Otherwise, I will drop the data of that day.

How can I do it in Pandas?

Comment: `df[df[['Data1', 'Data2']].gt(4).any(1)]` ..?

Comment: Also, just a tip, if you rename column `Hour(LT)` to just `Hour`, you can do `df['DateTime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']])`

Comment: @ChrisA eventually dropped those columns thinking as unnecessary as I already set the index as DatetimeIndex #Drop unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour(LT)', 'DN(LT)'], axis=1)

Comment: how about create another dataframe based on `groupby()` followed by `count()`, then filter based on that?

Comment: @AdityaSantoso it's huge dataset, and groupby() followed by count() didn't work as the index is DatetimeIndex